# No provider for MockStore

Tags: angular, cypress, ngrx, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to test my `app.component` using cypress. The component receives data from ngrx store. I've followed the official docs to setup the test. This is the test setup:

```
let store: MockStore;
let initialState: { loggedOnUser: null };

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(AppComponent, setupCypressConfig<AppComponent>({
        providers: [
            provideMockStore({ initialState }),
        ]
    }));
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
});
```

I am receiving the following error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for MockStore!

It's weird becuase I have this setup in the exact same way in another component and it works fine. I'm using standalone components by the way.

I've tried the solutions provided in other SO posts to no avail. Other things I have tried:

- Injecting `Store` instead of `MockStore`. Like this: `store = TestBed.inject(Store);`
- Providing the actual `MockStore` to the providers like this:

  ```
  cy.mount(AppComponent, setupCypressConfig<AppComponent>({
     providers: [
        MockStore,
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
     ]
  }));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by replacing `store = TestBed.Inject(MockStore)` with `store = createMockStore({ initialState });`.

```
let store: MockStore;
let initialState: { loggedOnUser: null };

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(AppComponent, setupCypressConfig<AppComponent>({
        providers: [
            provideMockStore({ initialState }),
        ]
    }));
    store = createMockStore({ initialState });
});
```